# AWS Web Servers some PDF Files don't display on the webpage, instead they automatically download

Tags: amazon-web-services

Good day,

I'm currently trying to display PDF files in an iFrame but for some reason, they just auto-download whenever I visit the links.
Here's a file which auto-downloads:
Here's a file which displays as normal:

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your 2 files is the Content-Type:

1. The first has Content-Type: application/octet-stream
2. The second has Content-Type: application/pdf

**application/octet-stream** is considered an unknown binary file and browsers download it directly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#applicationoctet-stream).

You can fix it by going to the S3 console and changing the first file Content-Type metadata to **application/pdf**.
More information on editing metadata: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/add-object-metadata.html